# Using partial over a collection, reduce -vs- apply

Tags: clojure

I have this curious demonstration of partials. Here is the code:

Start by declaring a vector and a partial. As expected, reduce and apply sums the integers on vector `a`:

```
> (def a [1 2 3 4 5])
> (def p (partial + 10))
> (apply + a)
15
> (reduce + a)
15
```

Now, using apply on the partial `p` and vector `a`, I'm getting the sum of `a` and the `+10` from the partial, which makes sense:

```
> (apply p a)
25
```

Now, using `(reduce)` makes no sense to me. Where is `55` coming from?

```
> (reduce p a)
55
```

The closest I can come up with is, `(reduce)` version is adding 10 from the 1 index and ignoring the zero index before adding everything together:

```
> (+ (first a) (reduce + (map #(+ % 10) (rest a))))
55
```

I'm just curious if anyone knows what is happening here, exactly? I don't really know what answer I'm expecting with this, but I also don't understand what is happening either. I have no idea why I would get `55` as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `+` is variadic: it can be called with zero, one, two, or more arguments. When you do `(apply + a)` you are essentially calling `+` with five arguments and getting the sum back (`15`).

However, `reduce` treats the function as strictly binary and calls it repeatedly, with the result of the previous call as the first argument of the next call. `(reduce + a)` is `(+ (+ (+ (+ 1 2) 3) 4) 5)` which also happens to be `15`.

So your `partial` is also variadic and can be called with five arguments, as in the `apply` call: `(apply p a)` = `(p 1 2 3 4 5)` = `(+ 10 1 2 3 4 5)` so you get `25`.

The `reduce` on `p` is going to call it repeatedly as shown above, but this time the function adds `10` in each time: `(reduce p a)` = `(p (p (p (p 1 2) 3) 4) 5)` = `(+ 10 (+ 10 (+ 10 (+ 10 1 2) 3) 4) 5)` so you get four `10`s and the `15` making `55`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at [Sean Corfield's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66740262/1562315):

Given

```
(def p (partial + 10))
```

then `(p  x  y)` means `(+ 10  x  y)`, for any  `x` and  `y`.

So

```
(reduce p a)
```

means

```
(reduce (fn [x  y] (+ 10  x  y)) a)
```

... since the first argument to `reduce` is a function of two arguments.

No initial value is supplied, so `(first  a)` is used as such, and the reduction is applied to `(rest  a)`, which has four elements.

- All the  elements of `a` get added in: the first as the initial value;
  the others by reduction.
- The `10` gets added on in every cycle of the reduction: four times.

So the final result is the same as

```
(+ (* 10 (dec (count  a))) (reduce + a))
```

In this case, `55`.